How to expand Macros of a huge project
Is there an easy way to get entire definition of ValeTy。It it diffcult to complile the single file with -E option.
llvm-projct part of Value.h code
  /// Concrete subclass of this.
  ///
  /// An enumeration for keeping track of the concrete subclass of Value that
  /// is actually instantiated. Values of this enumeration are kept in the
  /// Value classes SubclassID field. They are used for concrete type
  /// identification.
  enum ValueTy { 
    #define HANDLE_VALUE(Name) Name##Val,
    #include "llvm/IR/Value.def"

    // Markers:
    #define HANDLE_CONSTANT_MARKER(Marker, Constant) Marker = Constant##Val,
    #include "llvm/IR/Value.def"
  };

the include lines are like this.
HANDLE_VALUE(Argument)
HANDLE_VALUE(BasicBlock)


It can be parsed by clangd, but I don't know how to get the entire.

"It it diffcult to complile the single file with -E option." How do you want the result then?

Some build systems allow you to get compile commands as json file, you can look up command there and just add -E. Or if it doesn't work, you could use verbose mode of your build system and grep to find correct command for the interesting file. If your build system doesn't allow compiling header files separately, add source file that only has single line with include and look up command for this file.

Try find how cppinsights works here is repo.
